# Reducing Time Complexity and return formatted objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

We have a JSON object which consists of records where we need to create json in a particular formats so that the created object can be used in future:
Following is the JSON from which we need to create six more JSON objects which consist of unique(3) and grouped(3) records.

```
[
{
  "Tin": "123123", "TinName": "TinName1",
  "Npi": "1234", "NpiName": "Sample1",
  "Speciality": "Speciality1"
},
{
  "Tin": "123123", "TinName": "TinName1",
  "Npi": "2345", "NpiName": "Sample2",
  "Speciality": "Speciality2"
},
{
  "Tin": "234234", "TinName": "TinName2",
  "Npi": "3456", "NpiName": "Sample3",
  "Speciality": "Speciality3"
},
{
  "Tin": "345345", "TinName": "TinName3",
  "Npi": "3456", "NpiName": "Sample3",
  "Speciality": "Speciality4"
},
{
  "Tin": "456456", "TinName": "TinName4",
  "Npi": "4567", "NpiName": "Sample4",
  "Speciality": "Speciality4"
}
]
```

You can find that Each Tin, Npi, and Speciality keys have multiple records mapped with other keys.(For Ex. I have shown 2 records[tin:123123 has two NPI 1234,2345]).

Unique Tins:

```
[{Tin: "123123", TinName: "TinName1"}
{Tin: "234234", TinName: "TinName2"}
{Tin: "345345", TinName: "TinName3"}
{Tin: "456456", TinName: "TinName4"}]
```

Unique Npis:

```
[{Npi: "1234", NpiName: "Sample1"}
{Npi: "2345", NpiName: "Sample2"}
{Npi: "3456", NpiName: "Sample3"}
{Npi: "4567", NpiName: "Sample4"}]
```

Unique Speciality:

```
[{Speciality: "Speciality1"}
{Speciality: "Speciality2"}
{Speciality: "Speciality3"}
{Speciality: "Speciality4"}]
```

Group Tins. (In this way Group NPIs and Group Specialities are also created.)

```
{
 123123: [
  {
    "TinName": "TinName1",
    "Npi": "1234", "NpiName": "Sample1",
    "Speciality": "Speciality1"
  },
  {
    "TinName": "TinName1",
    "Npi": "2345", "NpiName": "Sample2",
    "Speciality": "Speciality2"
  }
 ],
  234234: [
  {
    "TinName": "TinName2",
    "Npi": "3456", "NpiName": "Sample3",
    "Speciality": "Speciality3"
  }
 ],
  345345: [
  {
    "TinName": "TinName3",
    "Npi": "3456", "NpiName": "Sample3",
    "Speciality": "Speciality4"
  }
 ],
  456456: [
  {
    "TinName": "TinName4",
    "Npi": "4567", "NpiName": "Sample4",
    "Speciality": "Speciality4"
  }
 ]
}
```

Code: I have used map() and reduce() such that Unique records can be obtained. For grouped i used reduce(). But from the code the timecomplexity will increase for millions of records. Is there any way to obtain the result in single or two interations.

```
          //uniq Tin
          finalJson[0] = jsonFile.map(item => ({
            Tin: item.Tin,
            TinName: item.TinName
          })).reduce(function (previous, current) {
            const object = previous.filter(i => i.Tin === current.Tin);
            if (object.length === 0) {
              previous.push(current);
            }
            return previous;
          }, []);

          //uniq Npi
          finalJson[1] = jsonFile.map(item => ({
            Npi: item.Npi,
            NpiName: item.NpiName
          })).reduce(function (previous, current) {
            const object = previous.filter(i => i.Npi === current.Npi);
            if (object.length === 0) {
              previous.push(current);
            }
            return previous;
          }, []);

          //unq Speciality
          finalJson[2] = jsonFile.map(item => ({
            Speciality: item.Speciality
          })).reduce(function (previous, current) {
            const object = previous.filter(i => i.Speciality === current.Speciality);
            if (object.length === 0) {
              previous.push(current);
            }
            return previous;
          }, []);

          //groupedTin
            finalJson[3] = jsonFile.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            const { Tin, ...rest } = cur;
            if (!acc[Tin]) {
              acc[Tin] = [];
            }
            acc[Tin].push(rest);
            return acc;
          }, {});

          //groupedNpi
           finalJson[4] = jsonFile.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            const { Npi, ...rest } = cur;
            if (!acc[Npi]) {
              acc[Npi] = [];
            }
            acc[Npi].push(rest);
            return acc;
          }, {});

          //groupedSpeciality
          finalJson[5] = jsonFile.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            const { Speciality, ...rest } = cur;
            if (!acc[Speciality]) {
              acc[Speciality] = [];
            }
            acc[Speciality].push(rest);
            return acc;
          }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, You should merge `map` and `reduce`. Please see next example:

```js
// Instead of

finalJson[0] = jsonFile.map(item => ({
    Tin: item.Tin,
    TinName: item.TinName
})).reduce(function (previous, current) {
    const object = previous.filter(i => i.Tin === current.Tin);
    if (object.length === 0) {
        previous.push(current);
    }
    return previous;
}, []);

// Please try
jsonFile[0].reduce((previous, { Tin, TinName }) =>
    !previous.some(i => i.Tin === Tin)
        ? [...previous, { Tin, TinName }]
        : previous, []
)
```

Above example is just a tip for you. No need to chain filter/map/reduce, You can use almost always only reduce.

Please keep in mind, that reduce callback receives third argument - index of the element.
So instead of writing `finalJson[3]`, you can just check in reduce callback the index.

Honestly, I don't have enough time for more extended answer.

Comment: I was looking for an optimised solution where single iteration can create all uniq Json and single integration for grouped json.